# how to write a mathematical formula using amsmath package?

Tags: amsmath

I want to write this mathematical formula:

```
f(x,y)={ 1 si I(x,y) < T
         0 sinon
```

How to write it in Latex?

Comment: \begin{cases} ... \end{cases} is the usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cases` environment, provided by the `amsmath` package, is the way to go:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment and '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\[
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{si $I(x,y) < T$}\\
0 & \text{sinon}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, it's « sinon ».

Comment: @Bernard - Mais oui! :-)

Comment: $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if it's « sinon »,}\\01&\text{if it's ‘otherwise’.}\end{cases} ;o)